# Calling a rest API windows 10 IoT with a Raspberri pi

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, iot, windows-10, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to do something as simple as calling a REST API using an universal app for windows 10 IoT but I can't find a way to do it.

Normally I would use:

```
private XElement ImportData(string sourceUrl)
    {

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        String source = wc.DownloadString(sourceUrl);
        return XElement.Parse(source, LoadOptions.None);

    }
```

but it isn't available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use HttpClient instead of WebClient.
**Try this**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = "URL here";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
return response.Content.ReadAsString();
```

Comment: I have a post here that details calling a REST service with HttpClient:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/05/how-to-use-httpclient-to-post-json-data.aspx

Comment: do you have an example for Put as the code I have does not work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464906/why-does-my-web-api-client-call-not-work-in-raspberry-pi2-iot